# Showing a set is infinite

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to make sense of the $\color{red}{\text{part in red}}$ in the proof below from PoMA by Rudin.

> **2.41** $\ \ $ **Theorem** $\ \ $ *If a set $E$ in ${\bf R}^k$ has one of the following three properties, then it has the other two:*
>
> $\quad(a)\ \ $ *$E$ is closed and bounded.*
> $\quad(b)\ \ $ *$E$ is compact*.
> $\quad(c)\ \ $ *Every infinite subset of $E$ has a limit point in $E$.*
>
> **Proof** $\ \ $ If $(a)$ holds, then $E\subset I$ for some $k$-cell $I$, and $(b)$ follows from Theorems $2.40$ and $2.35$. Theorem $2.37$ shows that $(b)$ implies $(c)$. It remains to be shown that $(c)$ implies $(a)$.
> $\qquad$ If $E$ is not bounded, then $E$ contains points ${\bf x}_n$ with $$|{\bf x}_n|>n\qquad(n=1,2,3,...).$$ The set $S$ consisting of three points ${\bf x}_n$ is infinite and clearly has no limit point in ${\bf R}^k$, hence has none in $E$. Thus $(c)$ implies that $E$ is bounded.
> $\qquad$ If $E$ is not closed, then there is a point ${\bf x}_0\in {\bf R}^k$ which is a limit point of $E$ but not a point of $E$. For $n=1,2,3,...,$ there are points ${\bf x}_n\in E$ such that $|{\bf x}_n-{\bf x}_0|<1/n$. Let $S$ be the set of these points ${\bf x}_n$ Then $S$ is infinite ($\color{red}{\text{otherwise $|{\bf x}_n-{\bf x}_0|$ would have a constant positive value, for infinitely many $n$}}$), $S$ has ${\bf x}_0$ as a limit point, and $S$ has no other limit point in ${\bf R}^k$. For if $\mathbf y\in{\bf R}^k$, ${\bf y}\neq{\bf x}_0$, then $$\begin{align}|{\bf x}_n-{\bf y}| & \geq |{\bf x}_0-{\bf y}| - |{\bf x}_n-{\bf x}_0| \\ & \geq |{\bf x}_0-{\bf y}|-\dfrac1n\geq \dfrac12|{\bf x}_0-{\bf y}|\end{align}$$ for all but finitely many $n$; this shows that $\bf y$ is not a limit point of $S$ (Theorem $2.20$).
> $\qquad$ Thus $S$ has no limit point in $E$; hence $E$ must be closed if $(c)$ holds.
>
> $\qquad$ We should remark, at this point, that $(b)$ and $(c)$ are equivalent in any metric space (Exercise $26$) but that $(a)$ does not, in general, imply $(b)$ and $(c)$. Examples are furnished by Exercise $16$ and by the space ${\scr L}^2$, which is discussed in Chap. 11.

Here below is what I think it means.

1. Let $S = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_N\}$. By defn of $E$, there must be $x_{N+1} \in S.$ But $S$ has only $N$ elements and so $x_{N+1} = x_i \in S.$ Suppose $x_{N+1} = x_1$. Then $x_{N+1} = x_{2N+1} = x_{3N+1} = \ldots = x_{N^2+1} = \ldots =  x_1$. So, $|x_1 - x_0| < \ldots < \frac{1}{N^2+1} < \frac{1}{3N+1} < \frac{1}{2N+1} < \frac{1}{N+1}$. This shows $|x_1 - x_0| < \frac 1n$ for all $n$ with  $N^2 + 1 \ge n \ge N + 1$. But because we can cycle thru $S$ indefinitely, we have $|x_1 - x_0| < \frac 1n$ for all $n$ with  $\infty \ge n \ge N + 1$. In other words, $|x_1 - x_0| < \frac 1n$ for all $n > N$. As $n \to \infty$, it should be the case that $x_1 = x_0$. So, suppose $x_1 \ne x_0$. Then there's a natural $n$ s.t. $n|x_1 - x_0| > 1$ by Archimedes. Contradiction. Thus $x_1 = x_0$ meaning either $x_1 \not \in E$ or $x_0 \in E$. Both cases lead to contradiction.

which in concise words,

2. For any $n \in \mathbb N, \ \exists x_n \in E \text{ s.t. }|x_n - x_0| < \frac 1n$. Then $\exists x_n$(say, $x_j$) with $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}0< \lim_{n \to \infty}|x_j - x_0| < \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac 1n}$ meaning $x_j = x_0$ which is contradictory.

Both $(1)$ and $(2)$ are supposed to say the same thing and be equivalent to the $\color{red}{\text{part in red}}$ of the proof above. Do they make sense? Are they equivalent(if less formal) to what Rudin is saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Rudin is saying in red is the following. First, if $S$ is finite there is $d > 0$ such that there are infinitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $|x_n - x_0| = d$. Proof of this claim: If $S$ is finite, $D := \{|x_n - x_0| : x_n \in S\}$ is finite. If for each $d \in D$ there are only finitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $|x_n - x_0| = d$, then there are finitely many numbers in $\mathbb N$, since $\mathbb N = \bigcup_{d \in D} \{n \in \mathbb N : |x_n - x_0| = d\}$, and a finite union of finite sets is finite. This is absurd, hence there is at least one $d \in D$ such that $\{n \in \mathbb N : |x_n - x_0| = d\}$ is infinite.

Now, take $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0} < d$. Since there are infinitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $|x_n - x_0| = d$, there is one such $n$ that satisfies $n \geq n_0$ (since the set of natural numbers smaller than $n_0$ is finite). But this implies $|x_n - x_0| < \frac1n \leq \frac{1}{n_0} < d$, hence $|x_n - x_0| < d$, which contradicts $|x_n - x_0| = d$. This proves that $S$ cannot be finite.

What you wrote in (1) and (2) doesn't make a lot of sense. (For example, in (1), why $x_{2N + 1} = x_{N + 1}$?) But I think you are overcomplicating things. Hope this helps!

Comment: Suppose $x_{N+2} = x_2, x_{N+3} = x_3, \ldots, x_{N+N} = x_N$. Then $x_{2N + 1} = x_1 = x_{N+1}.$

Comment: Why would $x_{2N+1} = x_{N+1}$ follow from $x_{N+k} = x_k$ for $k = 1, \ldots, N$? In any case, you may be missing the point of Rudin's argument (your original question). Is *that* clear?

Comment: Because $S$ is finite and we are cycling thru it. Take a look at the following passage for the same proof rewritten by another author: https://ibb.co/nQ584w1 My new question is Why is there some $x_j$ with $|x_j - x_0| < \frac 1n$ for all $n \ge N$?